# [__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to display a view after user accepts location sharing. Here is the code:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Denied");
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        NSLog(@"Accepted!");
        AlertViewController *aViewController = [[AlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlertViewController" bundle:nil];
        aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        aViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.window addSubview:[aViewController view]];
    }
}
```

But I get `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee6fc90'` error at line `aViewController.view.frame = ...`

I put breakpoints and verified that `aViewController` is not `0x00000` after the `alloc` statement. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Please suggest solutions.

Comment: what line cause application crash?

Comment: `aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);`

Comment: Doesn't seem like that could be causing that error. Does it really crash there when stepping through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect an issue in the xib file or in the AlertViewController's view initialization routine (i.e. viewDidLoad or loadView). The only way I can reason that the line setting the frame is crashing is that it's the first time you are accessing the view property, and views are lazily loaded.

I suspect that if you replaced

```
aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

with

```
UIView *aVCView = aViewController.view;
aVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

then you would see the crash on the first line, not the second.

To debug further, I would use breaks in AlertViewController's viewDidLoad or similar. And double-check everything in the xib.

Comment: Yes you are right, I checked and found that the app terminates whenever I first access `aViewController`

Comment: Okay, that's progress. That means you can narrow your hunt to the initialization code in your custom view controller. You can edit your question with some code from that view controller's view-loading methods, specifically addressing how the view is loaded (i.e. from storyboard/xib, inside loadView, or otherwise).

Comment: I found out that the issue was in `viewDidLoad`, I modified it and now the app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you were doing wrong in viewDidLoad, ddd?

Comment: I had put some string method, but the object was an NSNumber, and thats why it was throwing an exception

Answer (score 3):

The error you're seeing means that you or a framework is trying to get the length of a `NSNumber`. They don't have a length

To narrow this down, you should use an exception breakpoint:

1. Switch to the breakpoints navigator.
2. Click the + button on the bottom left.
3. Pick **Add Exception Breakpoint…**
4. Click **Done**. (the defaults are **Exception: All**, and **Break: On Throw**. Exactly what you want.)

Run and this time the debugger will break when the exception is thrown, rather than waiting for it to be unrolled and the application to be terminated. You'll get a **much** better idea what's actually happening.

Some possibilities:

1. You're assigning a `NSNumber` to a `NSString` property such as a textview's `text`. It seems that adjusting the frame on the view is what triggers it, but the bug is in other code.
2. You're using ARC, and you've got an object in a container class or some other form that's "weak" but not zeroing weak. It's been disposed of and replaced with an `NSNumber`, but other code is attempting to access the string at that location past its lifetime.
3. You have a custom view subclass that's treating an `NSNumber` like a string.

But this speculation is rather useless. Get the debugger stopped where the exception is raised; the problem will probably become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional statements, what type is `status`? You could be using the wrong operator or method. For example, if `status` is an `int`, `bool`, or a `float`, you would use the `==`. If it was a string, you would use `isEqualToString`, and if it was a generic object, you could use simply `isEqual:`. There are also specialized versions of the `isEqual:` function such as `isEqualToArray`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't think the prblem is with `status` because the error occurs at the line `aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);`